# Time/date issue when importing time/date data from one google sheet into another google sheet using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a google script code that grabs data from one google sheet into a matrix and copy and paste selected segments from that matrix into cells in another google sheet. The issue I have is that in the sheet that the script grabs data from there are some dates in the data with no associated time. These end up in the variables Trailer1 through Trailer5. When they get pasted in into the new sheet they change into a date and time variable and date is always one day behind and the time is 23:00 hours. To me it seems like the script is translating the dates and times into whatever timezone the script is in and is assuming the dates entered in the original sheet are at 00:00 on the date entered. I don't care what the time stamp is or if there even is one, I just need the dates to match. How do I fix this?

```
function myCopyPaste() {
  var now= new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var startrow = 3;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(year) //get current years sheet
  var id = sheet.getRange('D1').getValue();
  var length = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue()
  var boxsize = length-startrow;
  var rawsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(year);
  var rng = rawsheet.getRange(length, 1, 1,87 )
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();

  var ANUSED = rangeArray[0][19]
  var RunTime = rangeArray[0][27]
  var Railcar1 = [rangeArray[0].slice(5,7)];
  var Railcar2 = [rangeArray[0].slice(13,15)];
  var Production = rangeArray[0][26];
  var MedInv = rangeArray[0][30];
  var HPInv = rangeArray[0][33];
  var Trailer1 = [rangeArray[0].slice(36,43)];
  var Trailer2 = [rangeArray[0].slice(44,51)];
  var Trailer3 = [rangeArray[0].slice(52,59)];
  var Trailer4 = [rangeArray[0].slice(60,67)];
  var Trailer5 = [rangeArray[0].slice(68,75)];
  var TubeTrailer = [rangeArray[0].slice(76,81)];
  var Comments = rangeArray[0][86];
  
  if (RunTime>0) {
    sheet.getRange(length,4).setValue(ANUSED)
  }
  else {sheet.getRange(length,4).setValue(0)
  }
  sheet.getRange(length,5,1,2).setValues(Railcar1);
  sheet.getRange(length,7,1,2).setValues(Railcar2);
  
  if (RunTime>0) {
    sheet.getRange(length,9).setValue(Production)
  }
  else {sheet.getRange(length,9).setValue(0)
  }
  
  sheet.getRange(length,10).setValue(RunTime);
  sheet.getRange(length,14).setValue(MedInv);
  sheet.getRange(length,15).setValue(HPInv);
  sheet.getRange(length,19,1,7).setValues(Trailer1);
  sheet.getRange(length,26,1,7).setValues(Trailer2);
  sheet.getRange(length,33,1,7).setValues(Trailer3);
  sheet.getRange(length,40,1,7).setValues(Trailer4);
  sheet.getRange(length,47,1,7).setValues(Trailer5);
  sheet.getRange(length,54,1,5).setValues(TubeTrailer);
  sheet.getRange(length,65).setValue(Comments);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I figured this out. I went to file spreadsheet settings and found that the spreadsheet being imported was in mountain time and one being pasted into was in pacific. I changed the pacific spreadsheet time zone to mountain time and it appears to have fixed the issue.